# Is there something like maven-shade-plugin in C or C++ when linking?

Tags: c++, c, linker

I know when building Java programs, we can use maven-shade-plugin to resolve dependency confliction.

For example, if B depends on library A(version 1) and C depends on library A(version 2), both B and C can't build with the given version of library A, like the following

[image]

Though there doesn't exists one version A that satisfy both B and C, we can pacakge diffenrent versions of A into one executive. For example, we can rename library A of version 1 to `A_v1`, so if `A.x` exists in library A, it can be referred as `A_v1.x`. We can do the same to library A of version 2 by renaming it to `A_v2`.

Then, I find C/C++'s compile/link building procedure has similar aspects because it will also define and search symbols, so I am wondering if there are some ways to enable multiple version of one library be linked into one executive, by renaming tokens.

I will take the C library as an example. The function `printf` can be firstly renamed into `version_2_12_0_printf` or `version_2_13_0_printf` before linking, and the linker can somehow find location of the correct version of `printf` and link.

Comment: `objcopy --redefine-sym printf=version_2_12_0_printf your_binary` and just link with proper libraries.

Comment: @KamilCuk What if I what to redefine all symbols in the library? Can I just call `nm` and redefines all lines begin with `T`/`D`/`C`/`B`?

Comment: Yes. Will be hard, but possible. Anyway the general solution in linux is docker and other chroot environments management systems.

Comment: @KamilCuk What can docker do here? I want to link within multiple versions of one library into one executive, it seems to be a linking problem rather than a environments management  problem?